# A special character is added to my input every second, messing up my commands and passwords

Tags: arch-linux, boot, login, udev, input

I've been looking for any case similar to mine and still haven't found one.

The story:
I'm using arch linux, updated just last week, and it was working fine. I never configured auto-login, so I have to input my username and password everytime I boot. Today I decided to reboot, but when I tried to input my username I noticed a special character `^@` being added at regular intervals (aprox. once per second). I tried logging in while ignoring the character, and failed repeatedly, which led me to believe that the character was actually being added to my input, as if a key was stuck. I also tried changing to other tty but the problem persisted.

I didn't think it was a key stuck because to write that character I would need at least two keystrokes. I also booted using a bootable ubs stick and the problem did not appear, which proves it's not just a hardware problem.

Using the usb stick OS (and `chroot`), I updated with `pacman -Syu`, but it had no effect on the problem (note: I seem to have some messy dependencies with pandoc and haskel but I don't think they could have anything to do with this issue).

I turned it on and off a few times and noticed that the character started appearing in the boot sequence, right after the message of `started udev Kernel Device Manager`.

I never had anything like this happen to me, and it's very frustrating how it makes it completely impossible to even log in, so I can only work using the usb stick. I don't know how to even begin troubleshooting this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't happen to have any extraneous HIDs plugged into another USB port by any chance?

Comment: Seems to have happened before, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/1254863/null-character-appears-on-its-own-in-tty/1254892 .. No solution there.

Comment: @JdeBP you're right. I'm gonna try to understand the answer there and if it works mark it as duplicate.

Comment: @mozsalles I had a similar issue on my laptop, except that the NULs (^@) were triggered by folding the screen back too far — far enough to trigger a wmi event. After blacklisting the wmi modules, all was fine. Maybe your case is similar?